# Update properties of component in Vue.js

Tags: vue.js

I've been searching for the answer 2nd day. But still couldn't find solution.

I have the modal window template. And the main page template from where I need to update modal window size by clicking on the button (span). Shortly it's like this for HTML:

```
<template id="modal">
    <div>
        <div :class="'modal-' + size">
            ...
        </div>
    </div>
</template>

<template id="list">
    <div>
        <span @click="onDetails">
            Show Details
        </span>
    </div>

    <modal size="md" @showdetails="showdetails();" ref="modal">
        ...
    </modal>
</template>
```

And for JS:

```
Vue.component("modal", {
    template: "#modal",
    props: {
        size: {
            type: String,
            default: ""
        }
    },
    methods: {
        onDetails() {
            this.$emit("showdetails")
        }
    }
})

var List = Vue.extend({
    template: "#list",
    methods: {
        showDetails() {
            if(this.$refs.modal.size == "md") {
                this.$refs.modal.size = "lg"
            }

            <additional code here>
        }
    }
})
```

When I'm accessing this.$refs.modal.size for read - it's OK. When I'm just changing it from showDetails - OK if only this action in the function. When I'm put something else instead of  - size is not updating.

For example:
this.$refs.modal.size = "lg" - will work
this.$refs.modal.theme = "danger"; this.$refs.modal.size = "lg" - neither of them are updating

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You need to assign the attribute value of Size by the javascript method `setAttribute` . Example : `this.$refs.modal.setAttribute('size', 'lg')`

There is a working demo below:

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  methods: {
    showdetails() {
      console.log(this.$refs.modal.getAttribute('size'));
      this.$refs.modal.setAttribute('size', 'lg')
    }

  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.15/vue.js"></script>

<div id='app'>
  <button size="md" @click="showdetails" ref="modal">Click</button>
</div>
```

Comment: vue 2.6.10 - getAttribute/setAttribute is not a function

Comment: vue is a framework of javascript. All JavaScript function can be used in vue